# Does nvm have to be before rvm in PATH?

Tags: rvm, zsh, zshrc, nvm

Why does nvm is added before `/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin`
in `PATH` ?

```
echo $PATH
/home/user/.rvm/bin:/home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v5.1.0/bin:/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin:/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@global/bin:/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/bin:/home/user/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/user/.rvm/bin
```

My `.zshrc` file end looks like this

```
export NVM_DIR="/home/user/.nvm"

[[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ]] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm

export PATH="$HOME/.rvm/bin:$PATH" # Add RVM to PATH for scripting

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
```

I get the following error because of that.

```
rvm -v
Warning! PATH is not properly set up, '/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin' is not at first place,
         usually this is caused by shell initialization files - check them for 'PATH=...' entries,
         it might also help to re-add RVM to your dotfiles: 'rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles',
         to fix temporarily in this shell session run: 'rvm use ruby-2.2.3'.
rvm 1.26.11 (master) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]
```

Comment: Related https://github.com/creationix/nvm/issues/306

Answer (score 3):

`rvm` is expecting to be the first in your `PATH`. You can disable this warning so that you do not have this issue by adding the following line to your `.rvmrc` file:

```
rvm_silence_path_mismatch_check_flag=1
```

This should disable that warning.

Your `.rvmrc` file should be located at: `~/.rvmrc`. Create it if it does not exist.

Now, make `nvm` the first in your `PATH` and place `rvm` after that.

Comment: This doesn't answer the original question.